I want to climb smth: should I use に or を
I'm a little confused about whether you should use に or を with the verb のぼります。Should we say 富士山に登りたいです or 富士山を登りたいです？
Also, I think the word 登ります is also used for describing the action of getting on a bus. Should we say ’バスに登ります？’
Thank you!

Both に and を are correct for your sentence, but they differ slightly in the nuance they have. So the short answer is: either one.
For the act of getting into a vehicle that has a roof, or onto a vehicle that doesn't have a roof, please use 乗{の}る. バスに登る is fine if you mean "climbing on the (top of the) bus".
According to this Japanese A to Z and this Hatena Blog blog entries, に suggests that the top of the mountain is the goal of one's trajectory, while を suggests that the mountain is the medium along which the motion takes place:

富士山に登る
山を登って学校へ行く


I think it would be slightly more accurate to say that を indicates the medium along which the motion takes place.

@Saegusa 有難うございます、訂正させて頂きました。
